# What's the right/left inverse of a function?

Tags: math, coq

In his book Software Foundations, [Benjamin Pierce notes that](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/sf-4.0/Poly.html#lab101)

> The function `split` is the right inverse of `combine`

where `split` is `unzip` and `combine` is `zip`. I'm wondering just what it means to be the "right inverse" of a function and if there's also a left inverse of `zip`.

Answer (score 6):

`r` is a right inverse of `f` if `f . r` is an identity function (where `.` denotes composition).

`l` is a left inverse of `f` if `l . f` is an identity function.

Here, he is abusing the naming a little, because the function `combine` does not take as input the pair of lists, but is curried into taking each separately.

The reason why `split` is a right inverse of `combine`, and not a full inverse, is that the `combine` function drops elements of one of its input lists if their size differs. In that sense, `split` loses information that `combine` has no chance of producing.

That is, if you start with:

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [2; 3; 4]
```

Then:

```
combine l1 l2 = [(1, 2)]
```

And:

```
split (combine l1 l2) = ([1], [2])
```

There is no way for `split` to be a left inverse for `combine` since `combine` just dropped the elements `3` and `4` out of existence.

On the other hand, for any list of pairs `lp`:

```
let (l1, l2) := split lp in combine l1 l2
= lp
```

(You could write it `(combine . split) lp = lp` if `combine` took a pair as input)

Answer (score 2):

To complement @ptival's answer, the definitions of left/right inverse in a popular library are:

```
Variables A B : Type.
Implicit Types (f : A -> B) (g : B -> A).
Definition cancel f g := forall x, g (f x) = x.
```

thus if `cancel f g` holds `g` is a left inverse of `f` and `g` is a right inverse of `f`. See http://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.ssrfun.html

Note that this is more convenient that requiring `f \o g = id` due to lack of extensionality in Coq.

In math-comp, `left_inverse` and `right_inverse` are reserved for operators.

Answer (score -2):

You ask this question because you don't realize that *operations are not necessarily commutative*.

Here is convincing example:

Let v be a vector, and let S be the right-shift operator, which shifts all entries of v one position to the right and then sets the first entry to be 0.

Let T be the left-shift operator, which discards the first element of v, and then shifts all remaining elements one position to the left. Then clearly TSv=v, so T behaves as a *left* inverse of S, but STv not necessarily equals to v, as Tv discards the first element of v what cannot be recovered later by S. Therefore T is not a right inverse, of S.

See: [Generalized inverse (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse)

Answer (score -4):

It is referring to order in the pair:

RIGHT inverse split is :

```
Fixpoint split {X Y : Type} (l : list (X*Y))
               : (list X) * (list Y) :=
(* FILL IN HERE *) admit.
```

LEFT inverse split would have output lists in reverse order:

```
Fixpoint split {X Y : Type} (l : list (X*Y))
               : (list Y) * (list X) :=
(* FILL IN HERE *) admit.
```